# Reasoning for baking soda treating poison ivy rashes

Tags: chemical-biology, medicinal-chemistry

A quick Google search will show that baking soda (sodium bicarbonate) mixed with water in a 3 to 1 ratio will make a paste to be applied on poison ivy rashes. This is commonly advertised as a home remedy to poison ivy rashes.

Treatment for poison ivy ranges from mechanically removing the rash (scratching, which can make it worse), drawing the urushiol oil out, drying the rash, and simply waiting it out as your immune system takes care of it. Which method does this sodium bicarbonate paste use?

Basically, why should someone cover a poison ivy rash with a sodium bicarbonate paste other than it allegedly being an affective home remedy? Is there an scientific/chemical explaination as to why it might work?

Comment: @Close-voters Please avoid hasty close-voting. Just because the post has *something* to do with medicine **doesn't mean it should be closed as a "Personal Medical Question"**. Geez guys, this (topical application of baking soda solution) is a **general and common** mode of treatment, hence, this is a perfectly valid question and should remain open.

Comment: @paracetamol ""why should I cover my poison ivy afflicted arm" does feel personal

Comment: @Mith Meh... I guess that's still okay. I mean, putting the "paste" over the afflicted piece of skin *is* a commonly followed (apparently) method of first-aid. Wanting to know *why* it should be followed seams reasonable to me :P

Comment: It still does look like question for dermatologist.